# resizable для динамичного элемента

Tags: jquery, resize

Здравствуйте!

Есть в jQuery вот такая вещь:

```
$('#id_element').resizable({
    resize: function()
    {
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

Данный код позволяет отслеживать изменение размеров у элемента. Он работает только для статичных элементов, которые были добавлены ручками на страницу.

Возможно ли такое решение, но для динамично созданного элемента?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вызвать resizable для созданных тегов самостоятельно:

```
div = $("<div>").html("Loading...");
div.resizable({
    //...
});
$("body").prepend(div);
```

В вашем примере должно быть так:

```
$(function() {
      $("#resizable, #resizable-1").resizable();
      $('body').on('click', '.submit', function() {
          $('.result').append('<div id="resizable-1" class="ui-widget-content resize"><h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3></div>');
          $('.result').append('<textarea class="resize"></textarea>');
          $(".resize").resizable();
      });
});
```

Comment: Подобный код в моем случаи не удастся применить, т.к. элемент вставляется через аякс. Пробую такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/zt55ga8n/2/

Не работает он. Из-за чего это получается?

Comment: Добавил исправление вашего кода

Comment: Здорово работает! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кто подгружает инфу аяксом (ajax).

Тоже возникла такая проблема. Подгружал инфу с помощью аякса и вставлял элементы  внутри функции обратного вызова success функции.post . Так вот необходимо повторно инициализировать resizable именно в ней. Если после метода .post делать, то элемент все равно не растягивался.

Так понял это из-за того, что метод .post выполняется асинхронно и функция success еще не успевает выполниться, а значит объекты не созданы, но инициализация resizable уже выполнилась. Итог - новые элементы не растягиваются.

Либо вставлять элементы не внутри функции обратного вызова success.